# Search and replace a word in a string in Scala

Tags: regex, scala, date, formatting

I would like to replace the part of the text in a string

Example:

From

```
s3://provider/subject/foo=table/bar=NA/date=20140914
```

to

```
s3://provider/subject/foo=table/bar=NA/date=2014
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `I would like to replace the part of the text in a string`, which part of the text and with what?

Comment: Exactly the date should be replaced from YYYYMMDD to YYYY. Rest part of the string should not change

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/cN7qZ7/4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
(=\d{4})\S*
```

`(=\d{4})` would capture the first four digits along with the leading `=` symbol. `\S*` matches zero or more non-space characters.

Replacement string:

```
$1
```

Replacing the matched characters with the chars which are present inside the first group will give you the desired output.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cN7qZ7/4)

Answer (score 2):

If you always need to skip the date's last digits as in the string you provided you can just use:

```
"s3://provider/subject/foo=table/bar=NA/date=20140914".dropRight(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution.

Find: `(date=\d{4})\d{4}`
Replace: `\1`

Answer (score 0):

```
\d{4}$
```

Try this. Replaces the last 4 digits.

Replace by

``

See demo .

http://regex101.com/r/cN7qZ7/5

Answer (score 0):

In Scala:

```
val s = "s3://provider/subject/foo=table/bar=NA/date=20140914"
s.replaceAll("""(date=\d{4})\d{4}""", "$1")
//res0: String = s3://provider/subject/foo=table/bar=NA/date=2014
```

Or, I guess if the format is consistent:

```
s.dropRight(4)
//res1: String = s3://provider/subject/foo=table/bar=NA/date=2014
```

Answer (score 0):

For

```
val s = "s3://provider/subject/foo=table/bar=NA/date=20140914"
```

extract the date field,

```
val pattern = """(.*)date=(\w+)""".r
val pattern(_, date) = s
date: String = 20140914
```

and then replace (format) it for instance like this,

```
s.replace(date, date.take(4))
res: s3://provider/subject/foo=table/bar=NA/date=2014
```